# Grid system breakpoint override?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-redux-firebase

I need some help. I use material-ui Grid system, and my full page is responsive like a charm, but i need at grid components overflowX with fixed header, so only the Grid container should be a horizontal scrollbar, but i tried a lot of things but nothing works.
[I have this gird system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W9Gl.png) So i would like horizontal scrolling when im generated more grid item.

This is my code-snippet for this part.

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="droppable" direction={windowInnerWidth > 1280 ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'} type="droppableItem">
                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <div>
                        {windowInnerWidth > 1280 ? (
                            <Grid container spacing={6} ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} >
                                {mergedData &&
                                    mergedData.map((section, index) => (
                                        <Grid item xs={12} xl="auto" lg="auto" key={section.uid}  >
                                            <Draggable
                                                key={section.id}
                                                draggableId={section.id}
                                                index={index}
                                            // isDragDisabled={false}
                                            >
                                                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                                    <Card ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} style={provided.draggableProps.style}>
                                                        <CardContent key={section.uid} index={props.index}>
                                                            <MyWorkoutSectionListItem
                                                                type={section.id} // type
                                                                key={section.id}
                                                                section={section}
                                                                provided={provided}
                                                                index={index}
                                                                workouts={section.workouts.filter((workout) => {
                                                                    return workout.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.search.toLowerCase());
                                                                })} // subItems
                                                                workoutSections={props.workoutSections}
                                                                sectionName={props.sectionName}
                                                                defaultSectionId={defaultSectionId}
                                                                deleteSection={props.deleteSection}
                                                                handleWorkoutChange={props.handleWorkoutChange}
                                                                handleSectionChange={props.handleSectionChange}
                                                                changeMergeData={props.changeMergeData}
                                                            />

                                                            {provided.placeholder}
                                                        </CardContent>
                                                    </Card>
                                                )}
                                            </Draggable>
                                        </Grid>
                                    ))}
                                {provided.placeholder}
```

It would be great if somebody has idea for this problem.

Comment: I have created a [code sandbox project here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-dewdney-2vhn4?file=/src/component.js). This is what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, something like that, but my scrollbar not not working. i dont no why

Answer (score 1):

You need to Use `wrap={"nowrap"}` prop on container Grid component and also need to provide the `overflowX="auto"`.
Something like this

```
....
<Grid container spacing={2} wrap={"nowrap"} style={{ overflowX: "auto" }}>
  <Grid item>Hello</Grid>
  <Grid item>Hello</Grid>
</Grid>
...
```

I have created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-dewdney-2vhn4?file=/src/component.js) Code sandbox project with the exact implementations

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i the scroll take bottom of the page?